# json server angular put method doesn't work

Tags: json, angular, http

I'm using json-server and I'm able to do post and get. But I'am not able to do a update(put).

In my database, I have this data:

```
{
  "authors": [
    {
      "last-name": "LEFEBVRE",
      "first_name": "Jerome",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "last-name": "KAMA",
      "first_name": "tutu",
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update an author and in my angular service i do this

```
updateAuthor(a: Author) {
      return this.http.put<Author>(environment.apiUrl+'/authors/', a);
      }
```

And in my component i do this:

```
updateAuthor(author: Author){
    this.myservice.updateAuthor(author).subscribe(
      (result: Author) => {
        console.log("update author : ",result);
       }
    },
      error => {
        console.log("error author : ",error);
      }
    );
  }
```

but i have an error. can you tell me what's i'm going to do.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need an author id in your PUT url?

Comment: Hello @Omar, can you show me can i call my resource with id in put URL please. Actually, i  got error 404 (Not found)

Comment: Hello @ThomasSablik , i get this error localhost:3000/atuthors 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You should check https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#plural-routes

Comment: @obela06 I see a little typo in the authors url in the error you commented, if that's exactly the error you're getting then maybe you should check the value of apiUrl inside your environment config file. That aside, what I meant was something like this
this.http.put<Author>(environment.apiUrl+'/authors/'+a.id, a);